# Pandas: If a row contains this substring, update a cell in this row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a dataframe with several columns: `description`, `qty`, `client_name`. There are usually several hundred rows. I am looking for a code that will iterate over these rows, check if the value in the `description` or `client_name` columns contains a specific substring and  multiply the cell `quantity` by a fixed number.

```
description | qty | name client
apple       |  2  |  John Doe
orange      |  4  |  Bob WH1
banana      |  1  |  Bob WH2
DV mango    |  2  |  Eric
pear        |  1  |  Bob WH3
kiwi        |  2  |  Eric
```

I would like that for all the `name client` that contain 'john', multiply its `qty` by 4.

For all the `name client` that contain 'bob', multiply its `qty` by 2

For all the `name client` that contain 'eric', multiply qty by 2 **except all `descriptions` that contain 'DV'**, multiply its `qty` by 8.

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe and more details on what substrings you need to check for?

Comment: I edited the question to show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very specific solution, which assumes that the `client_name` column always starts with the first name of the client.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'description':['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'DV mango', 'pear', 'kiwi'],
    'qty': [2,4,1,2,1,2],
    'name_client': ['John Doe', 'Bob WH1', 'Bob WH2', 'Eric', 'Bob', 'Eric']})

# List of original columns
cols = list(df)

# Name to Multiplier value 
name_to_mult = {
    'Bob': 2,
    'John': 4,
    'Eric': 2}

#Create ausiliary, temporary columns
df['first_name'] = df['name_client'].str.split().str[0]
df['multiplier'] = df['first_name'].map(name_to_mult)

# Define a boolean mask, True if DV in description
DV_mask = df['description'].str.contains('DV')

# Compute the result
df['result'] =  df['qty']*(8*DV_mask + (1-DV_mask)*df['multiplier'])

cols.append('result')
df = df[cols]
df

   description  qty name_client  result
0       apple    2    John Doe       8
1      orange    4     Bob WH1       8
2      banana    1     Bob WH2       2
3    DV mango    2        Eric      16
4        pear    1         Bob       2
5        kiwi    2        Eric       4
```

Comment: This looks very neat thanks! What if I want to add another condition? For example: kiwi's `qty` should not be multiplied if the `name_client` is Eric.

Comment: If you are using mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive conditions, you can create different masks as `DV_mask` and use the "standard" condition ( which from my understanding is `df['multiplier']`)  on `1- (mask1 | mask2 | ... | maskN) `

Answer (score 1):

Assume dataframe `df`:

```py
substring = 'test'
fixed_num = 2
df['quantity'] = df[df['description'].str.contains(substring) | df['client_name'].str.contains(substring)].quantity * fixed_num
```

Comment: This didn't work, I just added an example for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

So after many tries, I found a workaround. It's not perfect but works in my case and might help someone so there it is:

```
df.loc[df['nameclient'].astype(str).str[0] == 'J', 'qty'] *= 4
df.loc[df['nameclient'].astype(str).str[0] == 'B', 'qty'] *= 2
df.loc[df['nameclient'].astype(str).str[0] == 'E', 'qty'] *= 2
df.loc[df['description'].astype(str).str[0] == 'D', 'qty'] *= 4
```